# What is the correct class structure for a queue of persons

Tags: python, class, queue

I would like to define in python a class which would be a queue of persons.

Persons have attributes such as `name, age, rank_in_queue` etc.

**Code** (I intentionally keep it short):

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self,name,age,rank_in_queue):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.rank_in_queue = rank_in_queue

class Queue:
    def __init__(self,queue):
        self.queue = queue
    
    def add_person(self,person):
        self.queue.append(person)

person1 = Person('Alice','30','0')
person2 = Person('Bob','52','1')

queue1 = Queue([])
queue1.add_person(person1)
queue1.add_person(person2)
```

I am pretty sure this is not the correct way of doing it for two reasons:

1. In class Queue, the attribute queue does not relate to anything;
2. A Person should not exist outside of a queue

Comment: Your code *doesn't do anything*.

Comment: for queue - look at `collections.deque`. `Person.rank_in_queue` should not be assigned. make it a property (e.g. using `@property`) and return current position in the queue when needed.

Comment: It's hard to know exactly what you need or what you are going for, but technically speaking, there's nothing wrong with what you have.  Though if that's literally all the Queue is doing, then I'm not sure why you wouldn't just use a list.  Making sure that a Person should not exist outside of a queue doesn't seem like the responsibility of the Queue. If you want it to be, then you need to have the Queue create the Person object itself.

Comment: @saquintes could you please precise what you mean by "you need to have the Queue create the Person object itself?"

Comment: @buran Could you please developp your comment in an answer?

Comment: @DeepNet If you don't want `Person` to exist outside of `Queue` then you could pass in the arguments for `Person` (name and age) to `Queue` and have IT create the `Person` object.  `def add_person(self, name, age): self.queue.append(Person(name, age))`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments - it depends on what functionality you want to implement.
First very basic example

```
import collections


class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age


    def rank(self, queue):
        return queue.index(self)


    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Person({self.name}, {self.age})'


alice = Person('Alice', 30)
bob = Person('Bob', 52)
charlie = Person('Charlie', 40)

queue = collections.deque()
queue.append(alice) 
queue.append(bob)

print(queue)
print(alice.rank(queue)) # this will print 0
print(charlie.rank(queue)) # this will raise ValueError
```

output

```
deque([Person(Alice, 30), Person(Bob, 52)])
0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "***", line 28, in <module>
    print(charlie.rank(queue)) # this will raise ValueError
  File "***", line 11, in rank
    return queue.index(self)
ValueError: Person(Charlie, 40) is not in deque
```

A more complex example

```
import collections


class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self._queue = None # single leading underscore indicates that it is for internal use only.


    @property
    def rank(self):
        if self._queue:
            return self._queue.index(self)
        else:
            raise ValueError(f'{self} not in queue')


    @property
    def queue(self):
        return self._queue


    @queue.setter
    def queue(self, value):
        if value and self not in value:
            value.add_person(self)
        self._queue = value


    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Person({self.name}, {self.age})'



class Queue(collections.deque):
    def add_person(self, person):
        self.append(person)
        person.queue = self


# create 3 instances of Person class
alice = Person('Alice', 30)
bob = Person('Bob', 52)
charlie = Person('Charlie', 40)

queue = Queue()
queue.add_person(alice)
bob.queue = queue

print(queue) # both alice and bob are in queue
print(alice.rank) # this will print 0
print(charlie.rank) # this will raise ValueError
```

output:

```
Queue([Person(Alice, 30), Person(Bob, 52)])
0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "***", line 53, in <module>
    print(charlie.rank) # this will raise ValueError
  File "***", line 16, in rank
    raise ValueError(f'{self} not in queue')
ValueError: Person(Charlie, 40) not in queue
```

All that said, your question may be better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and also may be considered as off-topic as [probably] opinion-based.